# Getting "Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point". while authorize from swagger ui page

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger-2.0

I am getting "Access Denied" error while click authorize button from swagger-ui.html page.

```
Exception :-  

2019-02-13 15:03:18.209 DEBUG 7960 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/hystrix/**'
2019-02-13 15:03:18.209 DEBUG 7960 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(authenticated)]
2019-02-13 15:03:18.209 DEBUG 7960 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@bbfccdd6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2019-02-13 15:03:18.209 DEBUG 7960 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1c8a3ec9, returned: -1
2019-02-13 15:03:18.211 DEBUG 7960 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : **Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point**

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Resource Server which is running on 8080 port

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

// password oauth
    @Value("${app.client.id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${app.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${host.full.dns.auth.link}")
    private String authLink;





    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        List<ResponseMessage> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(401).message("Unauthorized")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(406).message("Not Acceptable")
                .responseModel(new ModelRef("Result")).build());


        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
                ;
    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {

        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList();
        GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(authLink+"/oauth/token");

        grantTypes.add(creGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);

    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/**"))
                .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {

        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[3];
        authorizationScopes[0] = new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all");
        authorizationScopes[1] = new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all");
        authorizationScopes[2] = new AuthorizationScope("write", "write all");

        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("oauth2schema", authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(clientId,clientSecret, "", "", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
    }

    /*private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My API title").description("")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://www.example.com/api")
                .contact(new Contact("Hasson", "http://www.example.com", "hasson@example.com"))
                .license("Open Source").licenseUrl("https://www.example.com").version("1.0.0").build();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Application.properties

```
 app.client.id = fooClientIdPassword
app.client.secret = secret
host.full.dns.auth.link = http://localhost:9090/auth
```

ResourceServerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("my-resource");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"),"mySecretKey".toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/lib/*", "/images/*", "/css/*", "/swagger-ui.js","/swagger-ui.min.js", "/api-docs", "/fonts/*", "/api-docs/*", "/api-docs/default/*", "/o2c.html","index.html","/webjars/**","/hystrix/**").permitAll()                
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();                
    }


}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**", "/csrf", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().csrf().disable()
        ;
    }   

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }
}
```

Authorization Server which is running on 9090 port

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(jwtTokenEnhancer())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
        String pwd = environment.getProperty("keystore.password");
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"),
                pwd.toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

access token detail from postman:

```
**ClientId:fooClientIdPassword
Secret:secret

Username:admin@abc.abc

Password:admin

grantType: password

scope:read write**
```

using this credential it is working fine for postman.
with same credential i tried with swagger ui. it is not working.

[image: see here]